# (Object object) has no method effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I can't seem to understand what is wrong with the code. 
I've added jquery and jquery UI still have the :
[objec object] has no method effect error.

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = 'script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = 'container'>
        <div id ='one' class = 'inside'>1</div>
        <div id ='two' class = 'inside'>2</div>
        <div id ='three' class = 'inside'>3</div>
        <div id ='four'class = 'inside'>4</div>
        <div id ='five' class = 'inside'>5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript code :

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  alert('JQ on');

    $('.inside').mouseover(function () {
      $(this).fadeTo(1000,1);
    });

    $('.inside').mouseleave(function () {
      $(this).fadeTo(500,0.2);
    })

    $('.inside').click(function () {
      $(this).effect('explode');
    })
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think `effect` is defined in the plugin `jQuery UI`...

Comment: Try placing the `</script>` directly behind the `<script src=...>` block for the jQuery

Comment: Have you added jquery UI .js file?

Comment: you included the css for jquery ui, not the actual javascript file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've included the jQuery UI *stylesheet*, but not the JavaScript for it.

You need to add:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

(Or another URI that supplies it) after you include the jQuery JS.

Comment: I did not down vote this, but it didn't solve the problem. You can try it yourself

Comment: Well I don't know. But i did add a different link and it worked. So you get the prize :).

Comment: Maybe add this link to your answer as well : http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)